# Source script before httpd service starts

Tags: linux, httpd, systemd

Back in the good old days I was able to patch /etc/rc.d/init.d/httpd with some additional lines of code that executed on every apache start:

```
start() {
  echo "Setting variables..."
  source /path/to/my/script.sh
  echo -n $"Starting $prog: "
  check13 || exit 1
  LANG=$HTTPD_LANG daemon $httpd $OPTIONS
  RETVAL=$?
  echo
  [ $RETVAL = 0 ] && touch ${lockfile}
  return $RETVAL
}
```

*source /path/to/my/script.sh* is responsible to setup some environment variables needed for a PHP extension to work.

Anyway, after systemd, systemctl prevailed I'm not able to configure my system to automatically load script.sh variables before apache starts. When executing manually:

```
/usr/sbin/httpd -k stop
source /path/to/my/script.sh
/usr/sbin/httpd -k start
```

everything works fine.

What is the proper way to achieve this on Fedora 4.0 and similar systems using systemd service manager?

Comment: Add them to the unit's Environment= or EnvironmentFile=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use the ExecStartPre option in the unit configuration file. Plz, read http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html